# is this a firefox bug?

Tags: partitioning, permissions, mount, firefox, fstab

PROBLEM:

> firefox can't open files from a ntfs automounted partition on
>   **/media/myhd** (neither save downloads to **/media/myhd/downloads**)

INFO:

> **DISTRO:** Xubuntu 18.04

+

> **FSTAB:** UUID=38FEBFFAFEBFAE8E  /media/myhd ntfs **umask=0000,rw,suid,dev,auto,user,async,exec,allow_other,uid=*`noob`*,gid=*`noob`*,windows_names**
>   0 0

+

> **myhd** has been mounted successly, and **`noob`** is the current owner.

I think that issue is caused because firefox is currently in /snap/firefox and snap partition has another file system, or maybe, it is a firefox bug.